# Empty Tomcat thread dumps using jstack

Tags: java, tomcat, thread-dump, jstack

Trying to collect thread dump of Apache Tomcat8.5 in windows server I ended using `jstack` with `psexec` as follows(as using jstack directly wasn't possible, so I'm using pexec to execute jstack using syetm process):

> `PsExec.exe -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jstack.exe" -l 5340 > dumps.txt`

with **5340** is the PID of the running Tomcat8 process.

The execution started without any errors and it shows this output:

> ```
> PsExec.exe -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jstack.exe" -l 5340 > dumps.txt
>
>  PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> Starting C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jstack.exe on VMNAME...
> ```

When I check th dumps.txt I find it empty, even I'm running The command line as Admin.

[image]

Thnks for your help!

Comment: do you need the PsExec tools? Could you directly run jstack - and in case of errors use a `-F` param?

Comment: jstack.exe -F -l 5340 > mydumps.txt

Attaching to process ID 5340, please wait...
...
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 24.0-b56. Target VM is 25.231-b11
....

Comment: you need to use the same VM (version) for the jstack call, as the VM currently running your tomcat

Comment: @Andre Albert You're right, now it works, write your answer and I will accept it.

just another point jstack skips after some minutes, is this normal or it should continue execution until I exit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a conclusion to the discussion. You need to use the same VM version for executing a jstack command as the VM version you are going to inspect. In case of any errors, you could try a `-F` param to jstack.
Also, you don't need PsExec tools on newer VMs anymore.